# Period to comma TexForm conversion

Tags: latex, conversion

How can we instead of having a period as a decimal seperator have a comma when using a TeXForm conversion in Mathematica?
Example:

```
(M = {{2, 3}, {N[Pi, 10], N[E, 10]}, {1.234, 16}}) // 
  MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

becomes:

```
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 3 \\
 3.141592654 & 2.718281828 \\
 1.234 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)
```

We want to have a , instead of .

Comment: Not ideal in all cases, since dot may be used in other things besides decimals, but for your purposes you could just string replace by adding this to the end: `// ToString // StringReplace[#, {"." -> ","}] &`

Comment: Thanks a lot.@flinty

Answer (score 4):

```
myN[n_?NumericQ] := AccountingForm[n, NumberPoint -> ","]
(M = {{2, 3}, {myN@N[Pi, 10], myN@N[E, 10]}, {myN[1.234], 16}}) // TeXForm
```

gives

```
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 3 \\
 \text{3,141592654} & \text{2,718281828} \\
 \text{1,234} & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)
```

In Latex compiles to

[image]